# How to restore an inheritance that is broken in a folder?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, library

I want to restore a broken inheritance in a folder level is it possible to do so?

My permission have changed all over the site.

Comment: Do you want inherited permissions to your library? Was that library having permissions inheritance broken?

Comment: yes,because they are not there.

Comment: Have you tried `Delete Unique Permissions` for that folder ?

Comment: thanks Yayati it restores the removed users that are from the parent site..you a star.

Comment: Welcome. Also posted the same as answer below. Please mark as answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove Unique permissions on a folder, perform following steps:

1. Click on **`...`** to open ECB menu for that folder.
2. Click on **`Shared With`** --> **`Advanced`**.
3. Click **`Delete Unique Permissions`** in the top ribbon of the page.
4. Click **`OK`**. The status bar for the folder now reports `“This folder inherits permissions from its parent.”` The name of the parent appears next to the updated status.

For detailed information go through this link : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-permissions-for-a-list-library-or-survey-02D770F3-59EB-4910-A608-5F84CC297782?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1